# How to send POST request without using form

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to pass a parameter to a method using POST request. Since all data is generated after some logic, I don't want to use form to send such request. Is is possible in playframework?

Comment: Anything more which can light up your question?

Comment: example scenario: I've a method that calculates some value and I need to POST it to some other function. This is not an exact case but the task is somewhat similar

Comment: What do you mean by POST to a function? post to other url or sending data to another function?  Add what you have tries by your code.

Comment: I want to send a post request to some url. Is is possible to do that without using form and from the code itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [play ws](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWS). It allows you to do HTTP requests